# Symfony 2, Doctrine 2 - How to validate deleting child-parent relation

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have Section (Parent), Language(child) and Currency(child) entities. Their properties are normally validated via Validator, but I have problem how to check that user wants to delete Currency or Language entities, which are connected with Section entity. Symfony throws exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM Language WHERE id = ?' 
with params [5]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`mywork`.`section`, CONSTRAINT `FK_E2CE437382F1BAF4` FOREIGN KEY 
(`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`))
```

and I want to catch this exception and to send *normally* message with that what happened. I know that I can catch this error via try catch block, but it seems to me that is not correctly solutions in Symfony. And I don't know how to get error code from Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.

I would like find solution which similar to Validator. If property has not correct value, message will be send to user(client). For example:

```
My\WebBundle\Entity\Highlight:
properties:
    abbreviation:
        - NotBlank:
            message: "The abbreviation must be not empty."
        - Length:
            max: 8
            maxMessage: "Error value <strong>{{ value }}</strong> - The abbreviation can contain max {{ limit }} characters."
```

I have same problem with how to catch unique records and write message for user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator)
This way inside validate function:

```
// ...
if ($language->getSection() !== NULL) {
    // If you're using the new 2.5 validation API (you probably are!)
    $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
        ->atPath('section')
        ->addViolation();

    // If you're using the old 2.4 validation API
    /*
    $this->context->addViolationAt(
        'section',
        $constraint->message,
        array(),
        null
    );
    */
}
```

Same way you can check unique constraints, but i think better idea is to use [bild-in validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

EDIT:
if I get you right you have parent - child like below. Try to use preRemove LifeCycleCallbacks

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class Parent
{
    /**
    * @var ArrayCollection
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent")
    */
    private $children;

    /**
    * @ORM\PreRemove
    */
    public function deleteAllChildren()
    {
         //prevent 
         foreach ($this->getChildren() as $child) {
            $this->children->removeElement($child);
            $child->setParent(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. It seems like good solution, but I don't know how  I find out which operation is validating now. Because I use Entity manager for all operations simultaneously for example $em->merge() for insert and update and $em->remove() then I will use $em->flush(). And I need validate if language is independent only for remove.

Comment: @positive I have update the answer, hope this will help you. If not please post declaration of relations. I think i don't fully understand your class structure. 
Best

Comment: Hi, yes it helped. I will write my custom constraint validator according to your example. Your second solution adding of PreRemove callback will perform every iteration one query to db, right ?

Comment: @positive Yes, this is correct. Every child will be deleted by it's id. One iteration = one query.